# Let's find a way to encourage all the new users to participate more!

Tags: discussion, new-users

We have enough people to get 5 of them with 3000 rep and 10 of them with 2000 rep (first is included into second I suppose), but we don't have enough people to make 150 peers with 200 rep.
Let's pay attention to the new users, explain everything nicely (as bytebuster does, for example, with his "ласкаво просимо"), and encourage them to participate more actively.
I propose to share the ideas about the engagement under this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bytebuster has not invented anything by himself. All the principles used to be here at StackExchange for years. I just do it (whenever I not forget to):

1. **Vote**.

   - See a good post — upvote it.
   - See a bad post — downvote it. Don't care about -1 rep. point for yourself, think about how to make posts better.
2. **Comment** if you feel something's wrong (even if **your** feeling is wrong, and the post is okay).
3. See a new user with < 20 rep? — <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> on their profile, check if the user is new (this is their first post).

   - **Is he/she new? Say hello!** (it is fine to do that once for every new user)
   - Is their post bad? — downvote and tell them why (maybe, `-1` or `-2` is enough for a new user, don't kill them downto `-20`);
   - Is their post good? — tell them! (nothing works better for a newbie than an upvote and recognition)
4. Can improve a post? — Do it.
5. **Accept answers on your questions**. Many people simply forget that **we are here to learn**, and learning comes when one answer satisfies your request expressed in your question. So **let them know that their answer is the best**.
6. Check the [**Review Queues**](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/review) regularly. Personally, I have Review Queue as my **landing links** to [Politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/review), [Linguistics.SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/review), and [this site](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/review). See my results there ("recent reviews" link).